# why doesn't calculating distance between two places work?

Tags: angular, google-maps

i use google maps in angular .i need to calculate distance between one origin to many other destination , but the function returns the same answer to all.
what can i do?

CalculateDistanceBy(AddressStore:string) 
{ let res;
 this.request.destination=this.tempArrToSaveAddresses[this.mone]; this.mone=this.mone+1;
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
try
 { this.counter=this.mone; 
this.directionsService.route(this.request, (response,status) => { this.request.destination=this.tempArrToSaveAddresses[this.mone-this.counter]; this.counter=this.counter-1; 
if(status==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) { if(this.request.travelMode==google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING)
 { res= response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value; console.log(this.request.destination); }
 else 
if(this.request.travelMode==google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING) 
res= response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
 console.log("walking distance",this.response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value); console.log("km distance",this.response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text); console.log(res); 
resolve(res); }
 else { console.log("oops"); 
res= 0; resolve(res); } } ); } catch(error) { console.log("catch"); resolve(0); } }) }

---

```
tempArrToSaveAddresses:string[]=[];
 lengthArr=0;
  FindThreeMinPathPerProduct(product1:MinimumPath)
 {

  let productStores = this.listStoresPerProduct.find(sfp => sfp.Product.productName === product1.product.productName);
  if(!productStores) {
    return
  }

       for (let index = 0; index < productStores.Stores.length; index++) 
       {
        this.tempArrToSaveAddresses.push(productStores.Stores[index].addressStore);
        this.lengthArr=this.lengthArr+1;

        this.CalculateDistanceBy(productStores.Stores[index].addressStore)
        .then((res: number) => {

          if( res <  product1.min1  && res!=0)
          {
           product1.min1= res;
           product1.store1=productStores.Stores[index];
           debugger
         }
          else//|| res <  product1.min2
              if( res>=product1.min1 &&  res <  product1.min2  && res!=0 )
              {
               product1.min2= res;
               product1.store2=productStores.Stores[index];
               debugger
              }

              else
                  if( res< product1.min3  && res!=0)
                  {
                   product1.min3= res;
                   product1.store3=productStores.Stores[index];
                   debugger
                  }           
        }, () => {
          // reject
        })


      }


}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please format your code properly

Comment: i dont success .